# trigger click event itself on loading page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to achieve calling click event itself on selector "#map_canvas_tab". I do have click event register with that and it works fine but I want to call when page reload in document.ready function using jQuery or JavaScript

```
$("#map_canvas_tab").on("click", function () {

            //call me other code here 
});
```

I have used trigger but it is not working!

```
$("#map_canvas_tab").trigger('click');
```

Many thanks

Comment: I take it $("#map_canvas_tab").trigger('click'); is in document.ready? like $(function() { ...trigger });

Comment: have you tried $("#map_canvas_tab").click(); or try this to $("#map_canvas_tab").trigger('click',e);

Comment: Can you make a `fiddle` that shows this behavior?

Comment: Is the `#map_canvas_tab` added dynamically?

Comment: I am using easy tab jquery plugin and in 2nd tab, I got google map. When user click on #map_canvas_tab", it call my custom plugin and load google map. I want to call 2nd tab by default, and I have some small issue which i believe calling click event itself on page loading will solve it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found problem, it wasn't trigger but easytab. here is my solution

### Make 2nd tab active by default

```
$(function () {
        $("#selectPropertyTab").easytabs({
            defaultTab: "#sp_tab2"
        });
});
```

### Register Click event with require Selector

```
$("#map_canvas_tab").on("click", function () {

        //call me other code here 
});
```

### At the end, trigger event by code using trigger function

```
$("#map_canvas_tab").trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
<input type="button" id="btnclick" value="Click"/>

$("document").ready(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#btnclick").trigger('click');
},10);
$("#btnclick").click(function(){
    alert(1)
});
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Qaeav/

Answer (score 0):

the function will trigger on page load if you have like:

```
  btn.addEventListener("click", funName());
```

correct ways:

```
 btn.addEventListener("click", funName);
```

or if you have parameters

```
 btn.addEventListener("click", function(){ funName(param); }
```

Answer (score 0):

best solution is call a function:

```
$("document").ready(function() {

    //1- click function
    function mapCanvasTabClick(){
         //load map in tab content
    }

    //2- when load page:
    mapCanvasTabClick();

    //3- set selected tab
    $("#selectPropertyTab").easytabs({
        defaultTab: "#sp_tab2"
    });

    //4- bind to click
    $("#map_canvas_tab").on("click", function () {

        //call me other code here 
        mapCanvasTabClick();

    });
 });
```